# SFTP file to get and remove files from remote server

Tags: sftp, expect

I'm trying to write an expect script to pull files from a remote server onto a local folder, and delete them from the remote as they're pulled in. The script I have that doesn't remove them is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn sftp -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss sftp://<username>@<ftp server>
expect "<username>@<ftp server>'s password:"
send "<password>\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd <folder>\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "get *"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
interact
```

I could add "rm *" after the get command, but sometimes it loses connection to the server while getting the files and the script stops, so I'd like to remove files as I get them.

I tried setting up a for loop like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn sftp -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss sftp://<username>@<ftp server>
expect "<username>@<ftp server>'s password:"
send "<password>\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd <folder>\n"
expect "sftp>"
set filelist [expr { send "ls -1\n" } ]
foreach file $filelist {
   send "get $file\n"
   expect "sftp>"
   send "rm $file\n"
   expect "sftp>"
}
send "exit\n"
interact
```

But I get:

```
invalid bareword "send" in expression " send "ls -1\n" "; should be "$send" or "{send}" or "send(...)" or ...
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in that script, or if there's another way to achieve what I want?

Comment: G'deal. Personally, by the way, I'd implement this in a language with a native sftp library -- Python's [paramiko](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/sftp.html), for example, or Go's [`pkg/sftp`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/sftp) -- so you aren't needing to interpret output of `/usr/bin/sftp`, a tool designed for interactive human use. Lots of other languages have native SFTP libraries as well; shouldn't be hard to find one for whatever you're fluent in. Using a native library means you're getting filenames back as exact lists of strings vs needing to parse a stream

Comment: (which means needing to recognize and handle the escaping used in that stream should there be data with spaces, quotes, etc; the sftp wire protocol is [well-defined](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13), the command line tool's output format much less so).

Comment: From an expect point of view, the default timeout is 10 seconds. If you suspect `get *` will take longer than 10 seconds, add `set timeout -1` beforehand. I imagine this is the main cause of the script "unexpectedly" stopping too soon.

Comment: @glennjackman that was probably it, I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you get comes from the line

```
set filelist [expr { send "ls -1\n" } ]
```

This is because the `expr` command evaluates arithmetic and logical **expr**essions (as documented at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm) but `send "ls -1\n"` is not an expression it understands.

If you were trying to read a list of files from your *local machine* you could do this with

```
set filelist [exec ls -1]
```

However what you really want here is to read a list of files through the ssh connection to the *remote machine*.  This is a little more complicated, you need to use `expect` to loop over the lines you get back until you see the prompt again, something like this (untested):

```
send "ls -1\r"
expect {
    "sftp>" {}
    -re "(.*)\n" {
        lappend filelist $expect_out(1,string)
        exp_continue
    }
}
```

For more info see https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html and https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm .

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I was able to do the getting and deleting in the expect loop, so filelist wasn't needed.